# In Rails web app, styling changes subtly after clicking link

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Having a `HTML`/`CSS` issue, but I think​ it's likely related to `Rails` and its asset pipeline. The styling of my web app is fine upon the first page load (and hard refreshes), but when I click on a link, leave the page, and then go back to the original page, the styling breaks subtly, such that table headers are bold, many words get interrupted by a line break, all words look a little thicker, and the nav bar increases in height awkwardly, jutting out at the center. The only way to bring the styling back to "normal" is with a hard refresh.

I've scoured Stack Overflow for an answer, but it doesn't look to be related to Turbolinks. I've tried clearing my cache entirely. Also, this only occurs in Chrome — not in Firefox or Safari. I just have a gut feeling that it's picking up an extra stylesheet somewhere along the clicked link route.

Help me, Stack Overflow. You're my only hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of telling without your code, but it sounds like some other element is being added when you link_to another page, which is making your styling appear to be off.

I would inspect your formatting on your browser and see if there is another div being placed in when you link_to a page.

I would also make sure to put your reset.css file in, to ensure the browser isn't injecting it's own styling.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I would have totally posted code, but the ambiguous nature of the problem made it difficult. I had trouble even describing the issue! But your guidance helped me narrow down the possibilities, allowing me to ultimately solve the problem. The culprit was `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` (found in a base SCSS file): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering. Once I took that out, it stopped acting strange on a link click. At the end of the day, I do not know why that base SCSS file is only called after a link click, but happy to have this fixed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help!